# how to add property to property to an object based on the condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular

i have 2 arrays as show below:

```
arr = [
  { "zc": 33004, "score": 32.61 },
  { "zc": 33005, "score": 88.51 },
  ...
]

arr2 = [
  "type": "feature", properties: { "zc": 33004 }, geometry: { ... },
  "type": "feature", properties: { "zc": 33005}, geometry: { ... }, 
  "type": "feature", properties: { "zc": 33009}, geometry: { ... }
]

expected result = [
  "type": "feature", properties: { "zc": 33004, "score": 32.61 }, geometry: { ... },
  "type": "feature", properties: { "zc": 33005, "score": 88.51 }, geometry: { ... }, 
  "type": "feature", properties: { "zc": 33009, "score": 0 }, geometry: { ... }
]
```

Here, i want to add the `score` from the first array if the second array `zc` is matched inside `properties` object in each array of objects.

am writing a piece of code using spread operator as shown below

```
  arr.forEach(ele => {
      arr2.forEach(element => {
        element = {
          ...element,
          ...((ele.zipcode==element.properties.zipcode) ? {element.properties.scope: ele.zipcode} : {element.properties.scope: 0})
        }
      });
    }) 
  console.log(arr2);
```

but am getting compile time error. where am i doing wrong?

Comment: add more detail about the error. mention exactly what the error says.

Comment: 1.  map over arr2, and that transformation function in the map should 2. run a find against arr where the predicate matches the the inner and outer zc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a temp object for `arr` using `reduce`. Use the `zc` as key and the `score` as the value. This will make easier to check if `zc` exist.

Use `map` to loop thru the `arr2`

```js
let arr = [{"zc":33004,"score":32.61},{"zc":33005,"score":88.51}]
let arr2 = [{"type":"feature","properties":{"zc":33004},"geometry":{}},{"type":"feature","properties":{"zc":33005},"geometry":{}},{"type":"feature","properties":{"zc":33009},"geometry":{}}]

let tempArr = arr.reduce((c, v) => Object.assign(c, {[v.zc]: v.score}), {})

let result = arr2.map(o => {
  o = {...o}  //shallow copy the object
  o.properties = {...o.properties,score: tempArr[o.properties.zc] || 0}
  return o;
})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You get a compile error because you cannot use the dot inside an object propery name (like `{ element.properties.scope: ... }`)., So, you should do this as follows:

```
arr.forEach(arrElem =>
  arr2.forEach(arr2Elem =>
    arr2Elem.properties = {
      ...arr2Elem.properties,
      ...{
        score: arrElem.zipcode === arr2Elem.properties.zipcode ? arrElem.score : 0
      }
    }
  );
);

console.log(arr2);
```

But, I think this isn't the right way to do it. I think you should use `find()`, as the following:

```
arr2.forEach(arr2Elem =>
  arr2Elem.properties = {
    ...arr2Elem.properties,
    ...{
      score: (arr.find(arrElem => arrElem.zipcode === arr2Elem.properties.zipcode) || { score: 0 }).score
    }
  }
);

console.log(arr2);
```

(I don't change the `arr2Elem` directly, but I change its property `properties` beacuse the spread operator cannot use with subobjects).